# OWL complement in DL query (NOT)

Tags: owl, protege

OWL uses Open World Assumptions.  Thus if I have class Animal and property eats (domain Animal, range Animal)  Mouse, Cat (eats Mouse), Dog  and if I state the DL Query for instances (Protege 5.2) Animal and not (eats some) the result is empty.

Is there any way to make this query return Mouse and Dog with Owl e.g. make it somehow behave closed world?

thanks,

Comment: Please post your ontology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is as you implied: you have close the world in some way. I.e. currently there is nothing in your ontology from which the reasoner can infer that `Dog` and `Mouse` don't eat mice. This can be achieved by:

```
Class: Animal
    DisjointUnionOf: 
        Cat, Dog, Mouse


Class: Cat
    EquivalentTo: 
        eats some Mouse
    SubClassOf: 
        Animal

Class: Dog
    SubClassOf: 
        Animal,
        eats only (not (Mouse))


Class: Mouse
    SubClassOf: 
        Animal,
        eats only (not (Mouse))
```

I have written about some of the ways in which open world assumption issues can be avoided when using existential (`some`) and universal (`only`) property restrictions [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/26/understanding-owl-existential-property-restrictions/) and [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/05/10/understanding-owl-universal-property-restrictions/).

As an aside: You may want to rethink your domain and range restrictions on `eats`. What domain and range restrictions do is whenever, in this case, one individual eats another individual, it will infer that both individuals are of type `Animal`. This would mean if an individual of type `Mouse` eats say cheese, it will infer that the cheese is an `Animal`.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I was really hoping there was a simpler way to do it, in my scenario I have over 500+ instances so adding explicitly the negation seems to take over the advantage of using tooling.

Comment: Instances or classes?

Comment: You can always introduce intermediate classes that have the appropriate typing.

Comment: Instances.  I have lots of other classes but they cannot be conclusively mapped to a negative statement.

Comment: in my case Dog and Mouse are instances but even if I could make them classes the concern would be the same.

Comment: I've reprashed the question with a different attempt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414243/owl-closing-the-world-with-oneof